# You are given any $51$ integers taken from $1, 2, \ldots, 100$. Prove that there are two that are relatively prime.

Tags: number-theory

You are given any $51$ integers taken from $1, 2, \ldots, 100$. Prove that there are two that are relatively prime.

Comment: Have you tried using standard techniques like the pigeonhole principal?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Please tell us what you have tried, where you are stuck, whether you have solve a similar problem before.

Comment: @user5555: Such broad suggestions are never very helpful. Especially as the pigeonhole principle is not required here.

Comment: Presumably you need the additional constraint that the integers are all distinct.

Comment: @Bungo: That is implied by "You are given any $51$ integers."

Answer (score 6):

Hint: any two consecutive integers $n,n+1$ are relatively prime.

Comment: I would argue the next step uses the pigeonhole principle or something equivalent to it

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Make pairs like (1,2) (3,4) (5,6)......(99,100), Now you have 50 such pairs. Use pigeonhole principle